# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _PropertyDeferred

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I was making a blender addon but I can't seem to fix an error that occurs any time I hit the import button

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (

StringProperty,
)
from bpy_extras.io_utils import (
ImportHelper,
ExportHelper,
)
import struct

# Prompt user for file name

class CustomImporter(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import.custom"
    bl_label = "Convert ANM to FBX"
    filename_ext = ".anm"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Your custom import code here

        # Open .anm file
        with open(self.filepath, "rb") as file:
            
            
            
            print(file)


            # Read header
            signature = file.read(4)
            version = struct.unpack('<i', file.read(4))[0]
            num_bones = struct.unpack('<i', file.read(4))[0]
            num_frames = struct.unpack('<i', file.read(4))[0]
    
            # Create new armature and animation data
            armature_name = "SpongebobArmature"
            animation_name = "SpongebobAnimation"

            armature = bpy.data.armatures.new(armature_name)
            object = bpy.data.objects.new(armature_name, armature)

            animation_data = bpy.data.actions.new(name=animation_name)

            # Create bones
            bone_names = []
            for i in range(num_bones):
                bone_name = file.read(32).decode('utf-8').strip('\x00')
                bone_names.append(bone_name)
                armature.edit_bones.new(bone_name)

            # Set up keyframes
            for i in range(num_frames):
                for j in range(num_bones):
                    bone_name = bone_names[j]
                    bone = armature.bones[bone_name]

                    # Read position and rotation
                    px, py, pz, rx, ry, rz, rw = struct.unpack('<7f', file.read(28))

                    # Create new keyframe
                    loc_curve = animation_data.fcurves.find('pose.bones["{}"].location'.format(bone_name))
                    loc_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, px))
                    loc_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, py))
                    loc_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, pz))

                    rot_curve = animation_data.fcurves.find('pose.bones["{}"].rotation_quaternion'.format(bone_name))
                    rot_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, rw))
                    rot_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, rx))
                    rot_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, ry))
                    rot_curve.keyframe_points.insert(i, (i, rz))

            # Add armature to scene and set animation
            scene = bpy.context.scene
            scene.collection.objects.link(object)
            scene.view_layer.objects.active = object
            object.select_set(True)

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
            bpy.ops.pose.armature_apply()

            animation_data.use_fake_user = True
            object.animation_data.action = animation_data

            # Export to .fbx file
            fbx_file_name = fbx_file_name = self.filepath.replace('.anm', '.fbx')
            bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_file_name, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', use_selection=True)

        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
    def menu_func_import(self, context):
      self.layout.operator(CustomImporter.bl_idname, text="Convert AMN to FBX")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomImporter)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomImporter)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)
```

> Line 24 in execute: TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _PropertyDiferred

I tried looking it up but nothing comes up, does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: put `menu_func_import()` out of the class.

Comment: try `str(self.filepath)` to cast it to a string